# C# Message box and Visual Basic Input Box Focus

Tags: c#, vba, focus

I have a C# program that Needs to take an input from the user (via an InputBox). Process the information and give result as a message box. then the process is repeated until the user clicks the "Cancel" Button on the InputBox.

To achieve this I've added a reference to Visual Basic for the input box. for the result I use the C# MessageBox.show().

Now my problem is the focus on the input box/ message box. At first the InputBox had focus and the first MessageBox result was not in focus (the external program that Runs this Program had focus) and the rest of the MessageBoxes had focus until I clicked cancel. I've Implemented the MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly Option to the message box and now my problem is that the Second InputBox (and all others after that) lose focus.

Can anyone offer a solution to this focus problem? (or the right way to do this thing)

Thank you.

Comment: You need to show code as to what you are currently doing to display messageboxes... I don't know what an input box is for vb but I can almost guarrantee C# has its own version

Comment: For god's sake do not use VB6 combined with C#. Learn proper programming. Create a form, add a textbox and get that value.

Comment: sorry I have lost the *focus*. this is totally unclear and even after reading this 5 times i still have no idea what is actually going on

Answer (score 1):

Going off the top of my head here, but this should be in the ballpark....

Don't use VB6, create a new form called frmInput.  Set it's Border type to sizable tooltip in the property pane.

Add a layout table with 2 columns and 2 rows, put a label in the left column and a text box in the right column.  Set the textboxes left, top, and right anchor so it fills the width.

In the 2nd row merge the columns and Add two buttons, one called btnOK and one called btnCancel.  Now set the Form properties for Accept/Cancel.  Set Accept to btnOK and Cancel to btnCancel.

In the code behind add a Property Called Label of type string and another Property called Value of type string.

Set the constructor to accept two parameters, Message and Value.

Now add an event handler for txtValue's TextChanged event.  Have it update Value with txtValue.txt

Now add event handlers for btnOK and btnCancel.

In btnCancel_Click set this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel; this.Close();
in btnOK_Click set this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; this.Close();

Now to use it, be like

```
frmInput inputBox = new frmInput("Please enter your First Name:", string.Empty);
DialogResult result = inputBox.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK){
  //cool you entered something and clicked ok
  string firstName = inputBox.Value;
} else {
  //you canceled :(
}
```